# Importing module bundles in my file at the time of bundling

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I have created a bundle of one project and I am using that bundle in another project

but at the time of webpack getting that bundle code also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please check below example,

Comment: Please check below example,I have  created a typescript files bundle  for example A and now I am creating another bundle B but i have dependency of A bundle.So I have imported A  in B and now when I webpack  B then in b's bundle file I am getting A's code which is unnecessary.